# Removing default options in 'New' tool bar item and 'File->New' menu items

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, toolbar, menubar

I know how to contribute to tool bar or menu in my perspective, but is there any way I can remove some of the defaulted options?. For instance, in the 'New' tool bar defaulted options I always see the options 'Project...', 'Examples...' and 'Others...' that are programmatically contributed by the NewWizardsMenu. Is there a way, using extension points or code, to remove those entries from the menu while still being able to contribute with my own options?.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can try using *org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions* extension point.  *hiddenMenuItem* can be used to hide a menu item by ID, and worked to remove Java Projects from my `File>New` menu.  But I couldn't see Projects or Other... (at least from the Customize Perspective... Dialog).  You could try to hide the id "new" for "Other..." and I wasn't able to find the ID for "Project...".  If you use the Plug-in Registry view, you might be able to find what contributes that wizard.